# breeze.angular undefined breeze error in 1.4.16 ver

Tags: angularjs, breeze

After moved to 1.4.16 from 1.4.12 breeze version,started having breeze undefined error in [breeze.angular](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service) module.i checked the release notes but no avail,what is the breaking changes here and what is it supposed to do ?

im using requirejs.

```
require.config({
paths: {       
    'angular': './infrastructure/core/angular',
    'breeze': './infrastructure/core/breeze.debug', 
    'breeze.directives': './infrastructure/core/breeze.directives',
    'breeze.angular': './infrastructure/core/breeze.angular',
    'breeze.metadata-helper': './infrastructure/core/breeze.metadata-helper',
},
shim: {       
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular'          
    },      
    'breeze': {
        exports: 'breeze',
        deps: ['angular']
    },       
    'breeze.directives': {
        deps: ['breeze', 'angular']
    },
    'breeze.angular': {
        deps: ['breeze', 'angular']
    },
    'breeze.metadata-helper': {
        deps: ['breeze']
    }
},
priority: [
'angular', 'breeze'
],
urlArgs: 'v=1.0'
```

});

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might know. There was a mistake we fixed in v 1.4.16. Breeze was loading itself into window even when you used require to load it. We fixed that. Looks like the version of breeze.angular you're using is expecting it to be in window. That's a mistake. Do you have latest breeze.angular? if so, you may have to workaround by setting window.breeze yourself until I can fix in a couple weeks. I'm on vacation. Let me know.

Comment: Updating the breeze.angular module solved the problem.Thanks for answering.Enjoy your vacation :)